# How to simulate a click by using x,y coordinates in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseevent, mouseclick-event

Is it possible to use given coordinates in order to simulate a click in JavaScript within a webpage?

Comment: What's your goal? :) Are you trying to simulate a click on an image map for example?

Answer (score 192, accepted):

You can dispatch a *click* event, though this is not the same as a real click. For instance, it can't be used to trick a cross-domain iframe document into thinking it was clicked.

All modern browsers support `document.elementFromPoint` and `HTMLElement.prototype.click()`, since at least IE 6, Firefox 5, any version of Chrome and probably any version of Safari you're likely to care about.  It will even follow links and submit forms:

```
document.elementFromPoint(x, y).click();
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

Comment: @RadiantHex: yes, in fact IE was the first to implement it and it goes way back to IE6.  Chrome, Firefox and Safari 5 implementations are fine but Safari 4's and Opera's are incorrect (though workable).  See http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#documentview.

Comment: I'm so happy about this discovery!! =D Makes many things deemed impossible possible now =) ... or at least less complicated. Thanks!!

Comment: This does not appear to work with $.live() events, does anyone how to make it work with events created with $.live() as well?

Comment: @AndyE This is now working in following condition: I have webpage, I am loading Iframe from another domain than my domain. And I want to click in iframe area. Do you have some solution regarding this?

Comment: @parixit: nope, it's not possible.  You can simulate a click on the iframe but it will just propagate up the containing document.  Nothing  in the contained document will be affected (for very obvious security reasons).

Comment: @AndyE So its only possible for both of same origin (iframe and parent webpage). correct?

Comment: @Andy E - What do you say to [@torazaburo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16509592/165673) - wouldn't that be simulating a  "real" mouse click?

Comment: @Yarin: no, torazaburo's is doing what my answer suggests, that is just spoofing an event and firing it on the element.  A "real" mouse click, for example those at the OS level, would do more, like set focus or follow a link at the given x/y location.  Sometimes you see questions asking for that, but since it would only really be useful for nefarious deeds (like forcing clicks on ads), it's not possible.

Comment: @AndyE Is not working with <canvas> tag. I tried with your code at the page: http://codepen.io/r0ysy0301/full/grjaOp/.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in Firefox Nightly. To see for yourself, go to [this demo](http://thdoan.github.io/magnify/demo-map.html) in FF Nightly and execute `document.elementFromPoint(916, 263).click()` from the console. Now do the same in Chrome. The page redirects to Google in Chrome, but nothing happens in Firefox.

Comment: But, a canvas element needs to know click coordinates in order to detect clicking of objects in the canvas. How do we do that?

Answer (score 85):

Yes, you can simulate a mouse click by creating an event and dispatching it:

```
function click(x,y){
    var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    var el = document.elementFromPoint(x,y);
    ev.initMouseEvent(
        "click",
        true /* bubble */, true /* cancelable */,
        window, null,
        x, y, 0, 0, /* coordinates */
        false, false, false, false, /* modifier keys */
        0 /*left*/, null
    );
    el.dispatchEvent(ev);
}
```

Beware of using the `click` method on an element -- it is widely implemented but not standard and will fail in e.g. PhantomJS. I assume jQuery's implemention of `.click()` does the right thing but have not confirmed.

Comment: Saved me from a mess. My initial method failed but this one came to the rescue, thanks.

Comment: plus1 for not using jQuery. In contrary to the accepted answer, this one _does_ answer the question.

Comment: This is much, much more powerful than jQuery's `$.click()`

Comment: `initMouseEvent` has been deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/initMouseEvent

Comment: @torazaburo,  Seem not click in my test page: http://codepen.io/r0ysy0301/full/grjaOp/. This page using <canvas>. I tried with many method. But can't click in <canvas> at position.

Comment: This function isn't working in Firefox Nightly (v52) on this [demo page](http://thdoan.github.io/magnify/demo-map.html). Try `click(916,263)`.

Comment: Does this work so that a canvas element can use the coordinate to change drawing of things inside the canvas?

Comment: Instead of the deprecated `initMouseEvent` you can use `var event = new MouseEvent( "click", { clientX: x, clientY: y, bubbles: true } )` This is also shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36144688/384670.

Answer (score 48):

This is just [torazaburo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16509592/2067021), updated to use a MouseEvent object.

```
function click(x, y)
{
    var ev = new MouseEvent('click', {
        'view': window,
        'bubbles': true,
        'cancelable': true,
        'screenX': x,
        'screenY': y
    });

    var el = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);

    el.dispatchEvent(ev);
}
```

Comment: I had to change this to clientX and clientY since elementFromPoint is relative to the viewport https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint

Answer (score 3):

it doenst work for me but it prints the correct element to the console

this is the code:

```
function click(x, y)
{
    var ev = new MouseEvent('click', {
        'view': window,
        'bubbles': true,
        'cancelable': true,
        'screenX': x,
        'screenY': y
    });

    var el = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
    console.log(el); //print element to console
    el.dispatchEvent(ev);
}
click(400, 400);
```

Comment: It adds nothing to this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36144688/2000654

Answer (score -5):

For security reasons, you can't move the mouse pointer with javascript, nor simulate a click with it.

What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Aicule: thanks for letting me know! I'll add a bit of info to the question. I'm just experimenting, nothing really productive =)

Comment: In Chrome and Safari, you can fire a click at a specific x,y position. This is how [this demo](http://thdoan.github.io/magnify/demo-map.html) works. Firefox is the only browser where it fails, so maybe it's a Firefox-specific security policy.

Comment: Truth lies in the answer below, `createEvent()` + `initMouseEvent()`

Comment: In my case, testing.

Comment: You can definitely simulate a click with specific X/Y coordinates, although it won't behave exactly the same way.