# Jquery programmatically click in a specific X Y position in DIV

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simulate a click by using x,y coordinates? - Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277369/simulate-a-click-by-using-x-y-coordinates-javascript)

Would anyone know how to programmatically click in a div to a specific X,Y location? Using JQueryor plain javascript.

I'd like to click a button, which would simulate a click in a div via X,Y position.

Thanks!

Comment: Always advisable to search first @Peter.

Answer (score 0):

This is how an image would work. Maybe it works for the div?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').click(function(e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    alert(e.clientX - offset.left);
    alert(e.clientY - offset.top);
  });
});
```

Comment: I think that responds to a click, he wants to initiate a click event programatically.