# Dispatching a mouse event to an element that is visually "behind" the receiving element

Tags: javascript, css

On my web page I have two divs, A and B:

[image]

The DOM looks as follows (simplified). The main thing to note here, is that the divs are on the same level in the DOM hierarchy and they are not ordered by anything. Also, the outer div does not only contain A and B but also more divs C,D,E etc. B may not necessarily be overlapped by A. It could also be C, lying behind A.

```
<div>
    <div style="...">B</div>
    <div style="...">A</div>
</div>
```

A click handler is attached to the outer div, capturing mouse click events on A or B in the bubbling phase. A click into the intersection of A and B will cause an click event on A which bubbles up to my click handler that is now fired.

Now the problem: Under certain conditions the handler decides that the event should not be handled by A but should belong to B. If an event should be handled by B, the same click handler will be fired, but the event objects `currentTarget` property will be B instead of A.

How can I achieve this?

I've already looked at css3 pointer-handler and some event dispatching methods in JS, but could not really come up with a solution here.

**Possible solution 1 (not cross-browser compatible) ?**:

I think i might be possible to use the [pointer-events css3 property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events). If the handler decides that the event should be handled by B, it sets the pointer-events to none. Then, it retriggers the mouse click. *Question here: Is it possible to retrigger a mouse click with only the coordinates, not specifying a specific element?*

Anyway, the support of pointer-events is limited: http://caniuse.com/pointer-events

Comment: Have you looked at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: Yes, the main problem is, that I need to dynamically decide whether I want to have the event on A or B

Comment: already in place, what feature can I use?

Comment: Did you try to create a invisible element in top of target bottom element? or you can get the x, y, positions from your mouse event and if is inside the target element area and position dispatch the click event on it.

Comment: Thats true. I could do some maths and get all the divs whose boxes are around the clicked point. As the amount of divs I have to check can be thousands, I would like to avoid this, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to pass the event to `B` (using jQuery):

(*pseudo-code*)

```
var $A = $('#A'), $B = $('#B');

$B.on('click', function () {
  console.log('B clicked');   
});

$('#outer').on('click', function (evt) {
    if (Math.random() < 0.1) { // << pseudo condition
        $B.trigger(evt);
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hzErh/

---

**Update**:

using a function like this:

```
// this function should (did not enough testing) return all elements at a given
// point in the order of top to bottom.
var elementsFromPoint = function (x, y, root) {
  var buffer = [], result = [], el, i = 0, lim;

  while ((el = document.elementFromPoint(x, y)) && [root, document.body, document.body.parentNode].indexOf(el) < 0) {
    result.push(el);
    buffer.push({el: el, visibility: el.style.visibility});
    el.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }

  for (lim = buffer.length; i < lim; i += 1) {
    buffer[i].el.style.visibility = buffer[i].visibility;
  }

  return result;
};
```

you can get the elements for a given x/y coordinate. It's a bit hacky and needs more testing though.

```
$('#outer').on('click', function (evt) {
  var elements = elementsFromPoint(
    evt.pageX + $(this).offset().left,
    evt.pageY + $(this).offset().top,
    this
  );

  console.log(elements);
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hzErh/1/

---

**Update 2**: this version should give better performance for many elements:

```
// this function should (did not enough testing) return all elements at a given
// point, though the order is not representative for the visible order.
var elementsFromPoint = function (root, x, y) {
  var result = [], i = 0, lim = root.childNodes.length, bb;

  for (; i < lim; i += 1) {
    bb = root.childNodes[i].getBoundingClientRect();
    if (bb.left <= x && x <= bb.right && bb.top <= y && y <= bb.bottom) {
      result.push(root.childNodes[i]);
    }
  }

  return result;
};
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CTdZp/2/

Comment: @Erik I just wanted to simulate your *"Under certain conditions"* ;)

Comment: Ah, right! Thats a good solution then. Unfortunately I was not exact enough describing my problem. In my outer div there can be many div boxes like a and b and it is totally random which ones lies behind any other. So the main problem gets here, how do I know which box lies behind the clicked?

Comment: @Erik Ah, one thing you could do is a simple hit-test on the mouse-coords and all child-elements

Comment: Yes, we are already discussing this in the other comment section (on my post). Unfortunately I have really a lot of divs and searching will be costly (time/cpu).

Comment: Interesting update! I did not know about elementFromPoint. Looks as if could save me a lot. I'll check it out

Comment: @Erik I added another version. As you've written above that the number of elements *can be thousands*, the new version should give a lot better performance, as there is no redrawing involved.

Comment: @Yoshi Can I delete everything but the last example, to clean this up? Great function btw.

Comment: I'm not sure getBoundingClientRect is reliable on a scrolled page - http://javascript.info/tutorial/coordinates#the-combined-approach may help, but with bottom and right coords too.

Comment: @LukeStanley Yes please go ahead, just leave those parts that originally answered the question in such a way that it still does ;)

Comment: done, @Yoshi would also like to note these related question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277369/simulate-a-click-by-using-x-y-coordinates-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305477/simulate-click-at-x-y-coordinates-using-javascript?lq=1 so that this answer is easier to find