# Simulate click at x/y coordinates using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, simulate

How can I simulate a click at x/y co-ordinates using javascript or jquery?

I will use the script multiple times and I want the script to click on postion one then postion two then three then four and so one.

It is better without moving the mouse cursor, but if it has to move then that is fine as well.

Comment: `try {writing some code} catch(can't do it) {throw(tantrum);}`

Comment: I would like to hear more about what you are trying to accomplish... Call me a skeptic, but I am suspicious that you may be trying to cheat your way into some click-based income.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulate a click by using x,y coordinates? - Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277369/simulate-a-click-by-using-x-y-coordinates-javascript)

Comment: @Prestaul I wouldn't worry about it, if that's his goal he's going to be sorely disappointed

Comment: i dont understand why my question changed i didnt write it like that

Comment: @AhmedHafez, because Prestaul edited your question to, im his words *Fixed grammer/formatting, removed insultingly silly requests for good answers from "professionals"*, in order to help your question get better answers.

Comment: @AhmedHafez, I did [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing)... I did it in hopes that it would help you to get better answers, but if you feel that it no longer asks for what you need then please provide more details. We are all working to get you the best answer that we can.

Comment: ok no proplem @Prestaul 
but why there are giving me - negatives 
what ive done to them ?

Comment: You've done nothing to them. They are simply voting down your answer because your capitalization, punctuation and grammer were not correct and the actual question was hidden by other comments. The downvotes simply indicate that people did not believe that your question would be helpful to others.

Comment: they blocked me from making any other questions this is totally un fair

totally unfair

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simulate a click by using x,y coordinates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277369/how-to-simulate-a-click-by-using-x-y-coordinates-in-javascript)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This can actually be accomplished with the `document.elementFromPoint` method.  A jQuery example:

```
function simulateClick(x, y) {
    jQuery(document.elementFromPoint(x, y)).click();
}
simulateClick(100, 250);
simulateClick(400, 250);
```

**Edit:** Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/z5YjY/

Comment: why i see -2 
this is realy strange 

any way thank u for ur reply i will try it and tell u

Comment: im sorry but how can i use this code 
can u please give me the full code

to put before it 

<script type="text/javascript">

or what
and will it make auto click on postion 100 25 and postion 400 250 in the page even if it was an iframe 

and can i make also right click 

what jquey do i have to include in the head

Comment: @AhmedHafez, put what I wrote inside of a `<script>` tag, include jquery, and it should work. I don't believe that there is a way to simulate a right-click, and the technique for simulating a click inside of an iframe is going to be very different. If you need to be able to do that then the iframe will have to be on the same domain as the parent window, and I would recommend creating a second question. (i.e. "How to simulate a click inside of an iframe")

Comment: @AhmedHafez, to get jQuery on the page you can use `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @AhmedHafez, I added a working example that simulates 5 clicks and reports the text in the element at that position. Take a look and see if that helps.

Comment: @Prestaul thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you 
big hugggggggggggggggggg
great reply
:D
how can i help u too ?

Comment: yes i tried it it is realy nice and yes i want it for iframe actually
:)
i was tring yesterday all the day it didnt work on iframe i dont know why exactly it is supposed to work as it clicks and it doesnt matter what it clicks under the cursor or the hidden cursor 

but ur right it is better to make another question about it
but for this question
just one thing
can u make it like rather than redirect the page to pop up a new window 
and also what about the timing factor 

WE want to make this question to help anyone making anything
he could imagine :)

Comment: Yeah, this won't work with an iframe and if you have other questions about iframes, timing, and such then I would post them as new questions, but pay careful attention to your English or you may get downvoted before you get good answers. It might be worthwhile to have a coworker or friend review your questions for you.

Comment: omg they downvote me because of My English this so unfair 
so i downvote them if they write in arabic 

it is like uuhh what is this English bfff negative 
uff
they are like kids minds realy

Comment: any way thank u Prestaul i will make other questions as u wish 
and may be hire some one to check my spelling because i think there may be some proplems with e and E with this type of users

Comment: Not working with <canvas>. I tried with your code at page: http://codepen.io/r0ysy0301/full/grjaOp/.

Comment: @VănLộc, I don't see any click simulations in that code. What problem were you seeing with canvas?

Answer (score 6):

On a second take, I'd share my experiences, and update Prestaul's answer.

In most cases, you don't just want to click on an element to induce the 'onclick' event, but you would like to use the click info for something (eg.: move a slider there, or put a popup at that exact place).

I'm mostly using vanilla js, but it blends well with $.

```js
function simulateClick(x, y) {
    var clickEvent= document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initMouseEvent(
    'click', true, true, window, 0,
    0, 0, x, y, false, false,
    false, false, 0, null
    );
    document.elementFromPoint(x, y).dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
}
```

Basically this will pass down the correct pageX / pageY through the event, for further use.

I have updated the fiddle as well, to show a use of these coords:
http://jsfiddle.net/V4CdC/