# Is it possible to use a jQuery hook on an HTML element to trigger a click on a flash element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coordinates, flash

In reference to these topics:

[Simulate click at x/y coordinates using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305477/simulate-click-at-x-y-coordinates-using-javascript)

[How to simulate a click by using x,y coordinates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277369/how-to-simulate-a-click-by-using-x-y-coordinates-in-javascript)

Is it possible to use those methods described above to have an HTML hook kick off jQuery/javascript that can click x,y coordinates on a flash element automatically? And if so, how do I retrieve the x,y coordinates for the button on the flash element I'm trying to auto click (it's wrapped in a div).

What I'm trying to do is make my own full screen button that will trigger the flash player to go into full screen mode. The flash player doesn't have any hot key or other way to initiate full screen - the only way is to click the full screen button.

This was the only method I came up with that I thought might work for the above scenario, however if anyone has any other ideas as to how this could work please feel free to contribute, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else was wondering, I solved this with http://johndyer.name/native-fullscreen-javascript-api-plus-jquery-plugin/