# Simulate mouse-events in javascript on a div to contol a google map which is displayed by the div

Tags: javascript, google-maps, events

I want to use my own special input coordinates (x,y) to control a div element with a google map inside.

It is possible to create mouse-events, whose x and y coordinates inside a div (with a google map) element and the JavaScript API from Google Maps accept that mouse-events like a user creates events with a real mouse.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277369/simulate-a-click-by-using-x-y-coordinates-javascript