# Trigger mouse click by window offset in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I trigger mouse left button click by specifying X and Y pixels offset from upper left website corner via JavaScript?

Comment: I have no clicks, but I have to issue/trigger a click. So subscribing to any events is not a solution.

Comment: Found the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277369/how-to-simulate-a-click-by-using-x-y-coordinates-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fire an element's click event, and you can get an element using x/y co-ordinates - so you could fire a click event on the element at x/y. Since you tagged jQuery:

```
$(document.elementFromPoint(x, y)).click();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:document.elementFromPoint

Solution from [How to simulate a click by using x,y coordinates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277369/how-to-simulate-a-click-by-using-x-y-coordinates-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Well, using just `Javascript` as you asked, you can use `mouse` events, as you can read `X` and `Y` properties to get coordinaties from the `event` object, for sample:

```
// mouse move
document.body.onmousemove = function(e) {
   var x = e.X;
   var y = e.Y;
   console.log(e);
}

// mouse down
document.body.onmousedown = function(e) {
   var x = e.X;
   var y = e.Y;
   console.log(e);
}
```

To simulate an mouse click, you can call the event `onmousedown` manually, but you have to provide the [event parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/mousedown) (passing the coordinates, etc..), for sample:

```
document.body.onmousedown({X:120, Y:120 /* other properties */});
```

Comment: I have no clicks, but I have to issue/trigger a click. So subscribing to any events is not a solution.

Comment: You can force the call of these events and use as a click on window, look my edits.

Answer (score 1):

bind `onclick` event on document body, Try this code

```
document.body.onclick = function(e){
   if(e.clientX < 100 && e.clientY < 100){
       // your code here
   }
   alert("X =" + e.clientX +" Y"+ e.clientY)
};
```

Comment: I have no clicks, but I have to issue/trigger a click. So subscribing to any events is not a solution.

Comment: @IvanDoroshenko i'm not sure what are you mean exactly, this code is bide whole body in click event, you can only get specified x,y values in `if` condition this is also fake trigger click

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery mousemove to get the x y coords when moving and then fire the click within it if necessary. Something like:

```
$("body").mousemove(function( event ) {
    if(event.pageX == 50 && event.pageY == 50)
    {
        $("targetclickelement").click();
    }
});
```

Would be pretty inefficient though...

Edit - without jquery, use the same principle but with the handlers in Felipe Oriani's answer.

Comment: `OP` want to solution in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do such a thing, you could however catch the click then check the offsets and call function if it is within range

```
$('#d').click(function(event){
    if(event.offsetX > 50 && event.offsetX < 100 && event.offsetY > 100 && event.offsetY < 200) 
    {
        ///  Execute function
    }
});
```

Comment: I have no clicks, but I have to issue/trigger a click. So subscribing to any events is not a solution.