# how to doubleclick on WebElement using javascript with Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, webdriver

As selenium allows to execute java script, i want to click and double click on webelement or x,y co-ordinate using java script. I want to use java script because the underlined webelement is a Flash/svg objects on browser.

Please let me know how to double click using java script on a flash/svg webelement.

Thanks in advance...
Srinivas - Willing to learn new things :)

Comment: is your flash button is exposed? .. As per I know you can't use selenium for same. use sikuli for same , as you want to learn a new thing ;) :D :)

Comment: :) :D :) i like it :P "as you want to learn a new thing" Yep, I and my team are using Sikuli for automating flash/svg and we are getting much success over there. But the problem is that Sikuli actions cannot be multi threaded, and hence this question. I foresee that using javascript with selenium, multi threading is possible. Please help me with this question.

Comment: flash button is not exposed to qa. More over, we are migrating from flash to fully functional SVG.

Comment: Actually javascript is working directly on DOM but how we can suppose to perform operation using javascript even when the button is not exposed. It's seems impossible to me and If in case we can then I also love to know that :)

Comment: for same you need a channel(plug-in) which can interact between js and flash components.

Comment: refer it :- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-communicate-between-flash-and-javascript--active-3370

Comment: I never tried but if it helps then it will be awesom :)

Comment: In DOM at x,y location, java script can perform click/double click and selenium can execute the javascript on dom, and hence i guess we can. Lets see how it goes. I am trying this, on success, i will publish here.

Comment: Yes, I have post an refer link in below answer as well but want to tell you that co-ordinate of element can change according to different environment, it also depend on OS, pixel and resolutions.. So your script can be fail in different environments

Answer (score 1):

Use below code :

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);   
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(your_xpath));

   action.doubleClick(suite_name); 
   action.perform();
```

Comment: Thanks Mosam Mehta, but as i said selenium/Action class related clicks are not working as it is flash/svg based elements. I know the co-ordinates of the elements and i want java script to click  / double click the element.

Comment: in that case refer:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277369/how-to-simulate-a-click-by-using-x-y-coordinates-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks, similarly i am looking for double click.

Comment: Coming to co-ordinate changes, yes i agree but i will not hard code the co-ordinates, each time i take it from ui in some way. I will always refer to dynamic and at time co-ordinates only.