# JavaScript Clicking X & Y Coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any actual way to trigger a click on given X & Y coordinates?
These coordinates will be in an external `iframe`

What I want to do is put specific buttons when these buttons will be clicked, it will trigger a click event given x & y coordinates within iframe.

I tried code [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#Triggering_built-in_events), even though it says `not cancelled` still no success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simulate a click by using x,y coordinates in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277369/how-to-simulate-a-click-by-using-x-y-coordinates-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe browser security restrictions would prevent this from being possible especially if the iframe is loading a different domain.

Comment: Well, I thought so, I just wanted to give it a shot. I don't want to get any elements from that `iframe`, I just want to trigger a click event. It seems not possible.