# How to make JavaScript click a certain position?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, mouselistener

I'm new to JavaScript/HTML. I wanted to find out how I can get JavaScript to click a certain location. I would prefer it if no only basic/intermediate JavaScript is used, however the advanced JavaScript is also welcome.

Comment: Yes it is possible, and has already been answered. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277369/how-to-simulate-a-click-by-using-x-y-coordinates-in-javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simulate a click by using x,y coordinates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277369/how-to-simulate-a-click-by-using-x-y-coordinates-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, and has already been answered. See [How to simulate a click by using x,y coordinates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277369/how-to-simulate-a-click-by-using-x-y-coordinates-in-javascript):

> You can dispatch a click event, though this is not the same as a real
>   click. For instance, it can't be used to trick a cross-domain iframe
>   document into thinking it was clicked.
>
> All modern browsers support document.elementFromPoint and
>   HTMLElement.prototype.click(), since at least IE 6, Firefox 5, any
>   version of Chrome and probably any version of Safari you're likely to
>   care about. It will even follow links and submit forms:
>
> document.elementFromPoint(x, y).click();
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:document.elementFromPoint
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click