# jquery click on current cursor location

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I know that with jquery I can select an element and invoke a click. However, what I am looking to do is simply invoke a click on where ever the current cursor is.

For example something like this:

```
jQuery().click();
```

Comment: Whats wrong with hover or mouseover?

Comment: Do u mean    `$(document).click(function(e){console.log(e.clientX+" "+e.clientY);});` pointer location.

Comment: No I want to invoke the click not handle it if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help:

[How to simulate a click by using x,y coordinates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277369/how-to-simulate-a-click-by-using-x-y-coordinates-in-javascript)

maybe something like:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
   var x = e.clientX;
   var y = e.clientY;
   document.elementFromPoint(x, y).click();
})
```

Getting the user's mouse position can only be done via an event. Let's say your mouse is broken and it will track, but won't click, you could trigger a 'fake' click at the current position through other means:

```
var x, y;

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    x = e.clientX;
    y = e.clientY;
})

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    // if the key pressed was return, click at the current cursor position
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        document.elementFromPoint(x, y).click();
    }
})

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    // if the key pressed was space, click 50px below the current cursor position
    if (e.keyCode === 32) {
        document.elementFromPoint(x, y + 50).click();
    }
})
```

*tested and working, now you can click with your keyboard!*

Note that document.elementFromPoint(x, y) looks for elements at the coordinates *relative to the viewport*. So you'll be using `e.clientX` & `e.clientY`, not `e.pageX` & `e.pageY`.

Comment: I want to invoke the click not handle it if that makes sense. There is a long story behind this but it has to do with problems using a QA automation framework.

Comment: You need to get the current mouse position using an event. I've updated the answer above with some more on this.