# How Can I Make a Javascript Program Simulate a Mouse Click?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I want to make a JavaScript program simulate a mouse click wherever the mouse is on a timed interval.
I know of the

```
if(mouseIsPressed)
```

and the

```
if(mouseDown)
```

commands, but are there any commands that make my mouse automatically click, some kind of forceMouseDown command maybe?

Comment: If you want to do something like cookie clicker, you should use timeout instead. I mean, if you want to run a function every n seconds, you should set a timeout.

Comment: Ok, I will do some research on timeout and if I can solve my problem I will answer my own question.

Comment: It depends, what do you want to do ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click You can simulate a click event on any element you can select. If there's no html involved, just trigger the click handler manually.

Comment: What do you mean, I'm kinda new to this.

Comment: Why do you want to use a auto mouse click ?

Comment: What are you trying to click? If you're writing like a test for a web page, you can just select the button/input/etc that is supposed to get clicked and call 'click()' on it. If there's no html involved there's no difference between using a click to trigger a function and calling the function directly. So give us more info about what you're trying to accomplish with the click simulation.

Comment: I would like to use the auto mouse click to spam click an icon to see if my program bugs out when it is spammed.

Comment: And I'm not a fist clicker.

Comment: Then try selecting that icon in the html and call `.click()` on it in a loop. It will depend on what that click does if your program will crash or not. But then again, it's basically almost equivalent to calling that click handler manually like 100 times in a loop.

Comment: I guess that you should also know that I'm not trying to click a button in an HTML code but a rectangle in a canvas.

Comment: This has already been answered in this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277369/how-to-simulate-a-click-by-using-x-y-coordinates-in-javascript

Comment: I will check it out thanks.

Comment: Hmm, I assume you already have code to determine where on the canvas was clicked. I'd just run the click handler though a loop to see if triggering it too many times crashes anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to click a button, as I see from the comment, than just click the specific button with HTMLElement.click() in an interval.

Like this:

```js
var myButton = document.getElementById('my-button');

// Just for example
var clickCount = 0;
var clickStatus = document.getElementById('clicks');


setInterval(function(){
  myButton.click();
  clickStatus.innerText = ++clickCount;
}, 2000)
```

```html
<button id="my-button">My Button</button>
<p>Clicks: <span id="clicks">0</span></p>
```

Comment: So do you think that this would work in a canvas to simulate a click for a rectangle?

Comment: Also, is the part that times the click located here clickStatus.innerText = ++clickCount;
}, 2000) in the 2000 part?

Comment: Sure just change the `myButton` to point to the element inside the Canvas. As long as it's an HTML Element it should work just fine

Comment: The 2000 is the number of milliseconds to wait between each interval == 2 seconds..

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought but I thought I should check with you first.

Comment: This won't work for shapes drawn onto a canvas, since canvas' don't have html elements inside it. You need to calculate the mouse position compared to the canvas compared to the elements drawn on the canvas to calculate which drawn shape was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Can use [elementFromPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint) to identify top most element at current mouse position.

Combine that with a mousemove listener to track mouse position in page

```
var mousePos ={x:0,y:0}


setInterval(function(){  
  document.elementFromPoint(mousePos.x, mousePos.y).click()
}, 2000)

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
  mousePos.x = e.clientX;
  mousePos.y = e.clientY;  
});
```

Comment: May I ask what the e.clientX; and e.client does or simulates?

Comment: it is the pixel location within the document of mouse on x axis

Comment: what is mouseX or mouseY?

Comment: Well thank you guys for this, I will test it and be back later to give feedback on how it works.

Comment: You can't locate mouse if you don't track it's movement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134602/discussion-between-pi-guy-and-charlietfl).