# Offset a mouse click to occur somewhere else

Tags: javascript, css

Ok so just got a very strange requirement in an app that I am building. I need a mouse click to occur 50 px to the right of the cursor position. That is, when the user clicks in one place - the event should be registered 50 px to the right.

Is this even possible?

Comment: This does seem strange.  Could you get away with a hidden element that extends 50px in the appropriate direction which you use to trap click events?

Comment: You can fake it. Trap event.clientX and add 50 before doing anything on that spot.

Comment: inarilo, I suppose you mean preventDefault on the event itself and simulate an event on the desired spot? That could work too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by preventing pointer events on the body and then temporarily allowing them in a `document.onclick` handler. Then simulate a click using `document.elementFromPoint` (taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277369/how-to-simulate-a-click-by-using-x-y-coordinates-in-javascript)). Just add `50` to the `offsetX` value of the initial click event.

#### script:

```
let $body = $('body');
$body.addClass('locked');

document.onclick = function(e) {
  $body.removeClass('locked');
  let el = document.elementFromPoint(e.offsetX + 50, e.offsetY);
  if (el) {
    el.click();
  }
  $body.addClass('locked');
};
```

#### css:

```
body.locked {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```