# onLoad Click Function - RANDOM

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

Goal: Once the page is loaded a random area on the screen is clicked. Not a certain button or element, just a **random** click.

Maybe add an if function that if the click is successful then do another function?

Comment: Thank you for the constructive answer. As for the first part of your question, I do not know where to begin as an onLoad function would click the desired button element which is not the desired affect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simulate a click by using x,y coordinates in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277369/how-to-simulate-a-click-by-using-x-y-coordinates-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

using jquery, an approach can be...

```js
var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width())).toFixed();
var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height())).toFixed();

$('body').append($("<div class=myclass style=left:"+posx+"px;top:"+posy+"px;>Hello from random!</div>"));


$( ".myclass" ).click(function() {
  alert( "random area clicked." );
});
```

```css
.myclass{

position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: _"Once the page is loaded a random area on the screen is clicked."_ - How does your answer fulfill this requirement? O.o

Comment: Could you explain ;/

Answer (score 0):

What about taking all divs, choosing a random one and click on it?

```
window.onload=function(){
   var els=document.getElementsByClassName("*");
   els[Math.round((els.length-1)*Math.random())].click();
};
```

And a click cannot be *successful*, and you cannot detect that...

Comment: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
    at window.onload

Comment: @RealtimeDev it should work... what do els and els.length contain?