# How to build a CSS Selector from event object in JS?

Tags: javascript, events, css-selectors, event-listener

I created a simple event listener for clicks:

```
window.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  console.log(event);
});
```

From what I see, the event object contains a lot of useful data about the parent elements, HTML and CSS data of the clicked element.

Is there a way to build a CSS-selector (hopefully unique) from these event objects? If yes, are there any open-source solutions you can think of?

Comment: *"Is there a way to build a CSS-selector (hopefully unique) from these event objects?"* Yes, you can build a unique CSS selector for any element if you start with a reference to the element (such as `event.target`). That selector is not likely to be *useful*, however. Without knowing what you want to do with it, we can't reasonably answer this question.

Comment: I want to record user actions on my website using eventListenters, and then replay these actions using Selenium(browser automation). I was going to use CSS-selectors of elements to find them and click(there's a function in Selenium called find_element_by_css_selector()).

Comment: You can walk the DOM up to the top and create a selector such as `body div:nth-child(44) span:nth-child(3)`.

Comment: You could save the x/y of the event then [dispatch a click event at that x/y coordinate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3277417/2033671)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's entirely possible to build a unique CSS selector for any element in the DOM, because of the pseudo-class `:nth-child` which lets us differentiate between two elements with the same characteristics in the same parent.

Here's a simple example, which builds a selector using the tag name and its position relative to other elements within its parent. This example builds and shows the selector, then uses it a quarter second later to add a 'clicked' class to the element (which shows it in bold green):

```js
// Find the index of the given element in its parent
function indexOf(element) {
    var parent = element.parentNode;
    var child, index = 1;
    for (child = parent.firstElementChild;
         child;
         child = child.nextElementSibling) {
        if (child === element) {
            return index;
        }
        ++index;
    }
    return -1;
}
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // Starting from this element, build a tagname:nth-child(x) selector
    // for it, then prepend one for each of its parents up to BODY
    var element = e.target;
    var selector = element.tagName + ":nth-child(" + indexOf(element) + ")";
    while ((element = element.parentElement) != null) {
        if (element.tagName === "BODY") {
            selector = "BODY > " + selector;
            break;
        }
        selector = element.tagName + ":nth-child(" + indexOf(element) + ") > " + selector;
    }
    show(selector);
});
function show(selector) {
    console.log(selector);
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.querySelector(selector).classList.add("clicked");
    }, 250);
}
```

```css
#container, #container div {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.clicked {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <span>one</span>
    <span>two</span>
    <span>three</span>
    <span>four</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>one</span>
    <span>two</span>
    <span>three</span>
    <span>four</span>
  </div>
</div>
```