# Angular Material - hide menu on button's mouseleave

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I got menu that is being displayed on `mouseenter` event of a button. All that in toolbar:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <button mat-button routerLink="/products" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu1"
      #matMenu1Trigger="matMenuTrigger"
      (mouseenter)="matMenu1Trigger.openMenu()">Menu1
  </button>
  <mat-menu #menu1="matMenu">
    <div (mouseleave)="matMenu1Trigger.closeMenu()">
      <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
    </div>
  </mat-menu>
</mat-toolbar>
```

The menu is closed when `mouseleave` event of surrounding span, so far so good.
Now I want to close the menu on `mouseleave` of the triggering button as well by adding

```
(mouseleave)="matMenu1Trigger.closeMenu()"
```

When I do this and move mouse over this button, menu starts to flicker, like its being opened/closed every few miliseconds.

Why is that and how to hide the menu when mouse leaves the button?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kd8bue

**Edit:** After some googling I found out this behavior is caused by an overlay being displayed when the menu is opened as described here [How to open mat-menu on a single click and close other opened menu if there is any?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48467009/how-to-open-mat-menu-on-a-single-click-and-close-other-opened-menu-if-there-is-a). Not sure if what I would like to achieve is even possible because of the overlay...

Comment: Do you want to try this with `css` instead of `javascript`?

Comment: Try to bind menu's `opened` value to a component typescript variable instead and to change that value from the event.. Like: (HTML) `<mat-menu #menu1="matMenu" [opened]="varOpened">` (TYPESCRIPT): `var varOpened: boolean = false;` (HTML): `<div (mouseleave)="closeMenu()">` (TYPESCRIPT):`closeMenu(){ this.varOpened=false; }`. I don't have tested but I always acted like this way before with Angular Material's stuff so... let me know if it works!

Comment: @Deadpool: There is no such property as `opened`, see https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please review this closed issue on github

https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10378#issuecomment-372626596

When your `mouseenter` opens the `mat-menu`... a cdkOverlay is created and focus set to the `mat-menu cdkOverlay`, this immediately fires your `mouseleave` event because the focus is now on the overlay and not your button... even though your mouse is still over the button.

---

**Revision**

Please review the below stackblitz I did for this SO answer.

[How to open and close Angular mat menu on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53618333/how-to-open-and-close-angular-mat-menu-on-hover/53618962#53618962)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-nested-menu-yclrmd?embed=1&file=app/nested-menu-example.html

Comment: Thanks for explanation, that's what I was looking for, understand why is this happening. The workaround, yeah, not really but thanks anyway.

Comment: great job! It's just pity that such an elementary functionality isn't build in. Maybe using third-party component?

Comment: When you try to use the menu scrollbar with the mouse the menu disappears. Does anybody know how to prevent this from happening? @Marshal

Answer (score 1):

```
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
        <button   mat-button >Menu0 </button>

        <button mat-button routerLink="/products" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu1"
        #matMenu1Trigger="matMenuTrigger"
        (mouseenter)="buttonenter()"
        (mouseout)="buttonleave()" style=" z-index: 50000">Menu1
        </button>
        <mat-menu #menu1="matMenu" >
          <div (mouseleave)="matMenu1Trigger.closeMenu()"
          (mouseenter)="menuenter()"
          >
        <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Item 3</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Item 4</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Item 5</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Item 6</button>        
          </div>
        </mat-menu>

          <button   mat-button >MenuX </button>


          <button mat-button routerLink="/products" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu2"
        #matMenu1Trigger2="matMenuTrigger"
        (mouseenter)="buttonenter2()"
        (mouseout)="buttonleave2()" style=" z-index: 50000">Menu2
        </button>
        <mat-menu #menu2="matMenu" >
          <div (mouseleave)="matMenu1Trigger2.closeMenu()"
           (mouseenter)="menuenter2()"
          >
        <button mat-menu-item>Item2 1</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Item2 2</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Item2 3</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Item2 4</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Item2 5</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Item2 6</button>          

          </div>
        </mat-menu>

          <button   mat-button >Menu3 </button>
          <button   mat-button >Menu4 </button>
          <button   mat-button >Menu5 </button>
          <button   mat-button >Menu6 </button>


      </mat-toolbar>


    import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {

      name = 'Angular';
      isEnterMatMenuOpen = false;
      @ViewChild('matMenu1Trigger') _matMenu1Trigger
      @ViewChild('menuButton') _menuButton

      isEnterMatMenuOpen2 = false;
      @ViewChild('matMenu1Trigger2') _matMenu1Trigger2
      @ViewChild('menuButton2') _menuButton2

      buttonenter() {
          this._matMenu1Trigger.openMenu();
          this.isEnterMatMenuOpen = false;
      }
      menuenter() {
          this.isEnterMatMenuOpen = true;
      }
      buttonleave() {
        setTimeout(() => {
        if( !this.isEnterMatMenuOpen ) this._matMenu1Trigger.closeMenu();
        }, 50);
      }

      buttonenter2() {
           this._matMenu1Trigger2.openMenu();  
          this.isEnterMatMenuOpen2 = false; 
      }
      menuenter2() {
          this.isEnterMatMenuOpen2 = true;
      }
      buttonleave2() {
        setTimeout(() => {
        if( !this.isEnterMatMenuOpen2 ) this._matMenu1Trigger2.closeMenu();
        }, 50);
      } 

    }
```

Comment: The above code will work to hover and leave angular material menu items. The key is: style=" z-index: 50000" to make it works. It is a rough test code for the concept. You have to make the code looks nice if you want to use it.

Comment: This looks nice but only on first look. On second, sometimes its impossible to mouse into the menu because the menu closes. Also when I move the pointer from button to newly opened menu and try to move back to button, second menu duplicate pops-up right next to the opened one. Didn't expect having such an menu would be such an issue with Angular Material... Especially compared to competition like https://mdbootstrap.com, https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/ etc