# How can I do autoclick with javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

Friends I want to do this :
When I enter the website automatically click a point(x,y coordinates). I've been searching the net for two months, but I can't find it. Please help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simulate a click by using x,y coordinates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277369/how-to-simulate-a-click-by-using-x-y-coordinates-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try below java script code, where x, y are coordinates,

```
document.elementFromPoint(x, y).click();
```