# Clicking on graph created in Canvas (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, java, python, selenium, robotframework

**Bar Graph** is generated on Web Page (developed using **AngularJS**) using data from database. Graph is created using **CANVAS**.

[image]

Once graph is completed loaded, if you click on **Red** part, it will open one pop-up which will have table containing the values - **Total** and **Missed**. Same for Green - **Total** & **Hit**.

Graph will always have two colors - RED & GREEN.

I am trying to test this **Graph** using **Robot Framework**.
I am able to Click on graph and then read the value from popup table.

***Only issue is I am clicking randomly. I want to identify the RED and GREEN and then Click it.***

After inspecting above element in IE, below information I am getting for above Graph.

```
<div class = 'ChartWrapperArea'>
    <canvas width='2000' height='600'
     class = 'chart-bar ng-isolate-scope'
     id = 'pwFeedChart' style='display;block;'
     chart-colors='colors' chart-options='barOptions'
     chart-labels='barLabels' chart-data='barData'
     chart='pwFeedChart'>
    </canvas>
</div>
```

Please let me know the way how to identify the element in graph.

Preferable option is **Robot Framework** but ready for any other solution also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the coordinates of canvas using offsetLeft, offsetTop, width of the canvas. Ex.

```
var test = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
var left = test.offsetLeft;
var top = test.offsetTop;
var width = test.width;
// get the coordinates X and Y using above.
```

After that you can use jquery to click in that area below is the sample link for it.
[How to simulate a click by using x,y coordinates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277369/how-to-simulate-a-click-by-using-x-y-coordinates-in-javascript).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @gusaindpk. Will try and get back to you.