# Clicking by coordinates using js

Tags: javascript, html, web, browser, console

Is there any way to click an element by coordinates in a website using the console?
I know i can use element.click() but i need to use it with coordinates.
Something like:

```
Window.click(234,456)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simulate a click by using x,y coordinates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277369/how-to-simulate-a-click-by-using-x-y-coordinates-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate a click *event* like this:

```
document.elementFromPoint(x, y).click();
```

But this isn't the same as clicking normally.

Documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint).

Comment: No, you cannot trick an iframe into thinking youve pressed a button, that would pose a security issue.