# How to click a web element at its center via JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I basically have a web page and want to simulate clicks via console.
I tried to do this via
`document.getElementById("myButtonId").click()`
But the element only supports clicks at its central location.

Is there a way to click this element?

Comment: "But the element only supports clicks at its central location." What does that actually mean? Is there code for the eventlistener hat shows this?

Comment: > But the element only supports clicks at its central location.

Sounds like the element is not actually clickable and you are sending the click to a wrapper (outer) element therefore the click won't propagate. Might be helpful if you share more context and your actual HTML and/or more relevant code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to simulate a click by using x,y coordinates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277369/how-to-simulate-a-click-by-using-x-y-coordinates-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery your code must be:

`$("#myButtonId").click();`
or
`$("#myButtonId").trigger("click");`