# How can I automatically confirm a confirm popup on a web page?

Tags: javascript, java, android, automation, popup

my android app automatically load a specific form from a web page and at the moment the submit button open a confirm popup. I want to automatically "click ok" in the popup to continue to the next page from the form without the human interaction necessity.
I wanted to try using javascript to force the `confirm() function`  to return `true`, but the function is hidden in the `submitForm()` function code.

Comment: The app is programmed in java (android native), but the code uses some javascript injections to manipulate the web form.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to simulate a click by using x,y coordinates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277369/how-to-simulate-a-click-by-using-x-y-coordinates-in-javascript)

Comment: no. This only works if the button that I want to click is an html element from the page. In my case, the popup is calls by the web page, but is a android/browser template (like the `alert()` or `confirm()`).

Answer (score -1):

Silly solution, trigger a click at a specified coordinate:

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3277417/14406944 for reference.

Comment: This solution just work if the element I want to click is an html element from the page. But I want to click in a confim popup (like an alert popup).