# how do you click where the mouse is with javascript

Tags: javascript

This is what I have so far:

```
for(var i;i< 99999;i++){
  if(mouse.x == element.x,mouse.y == element.y){
    element.click
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to simulate a click by using x,y coordinates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277369/how-to-simulate-a-click-by-using-x-y-coordinates-in-javascript)

Comment: Please add an explanation as of what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @connexo I assume simulate click at mouse position

Comment: yes simulate click at mouse position

Comment: but you can loop to make an auto clicker

Comment: Why would you do that?  What's your larger purpose here?  If you want to take some action when the mouse hovers over a control, you can use `mouseover` for that (as @Bulog shows), but just forcing the mouse to click arbitrarily is a terrible user experience.

Comment: If you're running Javascript, then this is a web page you control.  In that case, you don't have to "simulate" actions at all.  You can call whatever functions you want to call.

Comment: yes @Emmanuel it dose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `window.mouseover` to listen the mouse event

```
var item;
window.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {
  // the mouseover target
  item = event.target;
}, false);

// now you can use the item
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener("click", spawn);

function spawn(e){
  console.log(e.clientX);
  console.log(e.clientY);
}
```

click anywhere in the window...

Comment: thank you but this only tells you where the mouse clicks it doesn't click where the mouse is