# Specify coordinates for click() for `<input type="image">`

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

When clicking the colored boxes on [this MDN example page](https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/html/forms/image-type-example/xy-coordinates-example.html), the URL shows the coordinates of the click.

When using `document.querySelector("input").click()`, the URL shows coordinates of `x=0&y=0`.

I want to programmatically click the button, using the console or a userscript, such that the URL shows the coordinates I specify.

What I’ve tried:

```js
document.querySelector("input").dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", {
  x: 55, // And also `offsetX` and `clientX`.
  y: 55 
}));
```

The documentation on [`MouseEvent`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent) notes that these don’t actually move the cursor, which is fine.

I tried putting a `<div>` over it, passing the click through.

```js
const newdiv = document.createElement("div");

newdiv.style.position = "fixed";
newdiv.style.height = "1px";
newdiv.style.width = "1px";
newdiv.style.top = "55px";
newdiv.style.left = "55px";
newdiv.style.pointerEvents = "none";

document.querySelector("div").prepend(newdiv);
newdiv.click();
```

This works for manual clicks, but `.click()` doesn’t do anything (because it’s a sibling?).
`document.querySelector("input").prepend(newdiv);` will bubble, but it’s still (0, 0).

How can I click at a coordinate?

I had already tried the answers of the suggested question [How to simulate a click by using x,y coordinates in JavaScript?](/q/3277369/20366663) before asking this question (it was one of the first Google results I found). This question is not a duplicate because the marked answer, firstly gets the element, *then* clicks it:

```js
document.elementFromPoint(x, y).click();
```

which is exactly the same as

```js
document.querySelector("input").click();
```

Comments suggest this is not possible, because it could make users click ads. Can it truly not be done?

Other solutions “click” the page / element, but do not submit the form (the URL does not change to show where the button was clicked).

Comment: Does this help? [How to simulate a click by using x,y coordinates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277369/how-to-simulate-a-click-by-using-x-y-coordinates-in-javascript)

Comment: Have you considered submitting the form with the custom URL instead?

Comment: `document.elementFromPoint(x, y).click();` is not the same because it gets the element (i.e., the input image) at whatever coord you specify, then clicks (it'll still show 0,0)

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I did consider it, but am not sure how to specify the coords. `document.querySelector("form").submit();` Can you use the URL above and the console to make the URL change appropriately?

Comment: @user900901 I think inserting two `<input type="hidden">` elements with the appropriate `name` attributes should be enough, e.g. `yourFormElement.append(Object.assign(document.createElement("input"), { type: "hidden", name: "x", value: x }), Object.assign(document.createElement("input"), { type: "hidden", name: "y", value: y })); yourFormElement.submit();`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon That does work and does change the URL. Thank you for the comment. I'm not sure about SO etiquette in this case: you've provided a solution satisfactory to me but it's not necessarily an 'answer' to the original question. However, as my question was specifically about making the URL change the coords, a click vs submit isn't an important distinction to me. I would mark it as an answer if you were to post it.  Regardless, you have my thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that setting the coordinates on the `<form>` when submitting via `<input type="image">` only happens for user-initiated events and not for synthetic events.
However, it’s possible to emulate the behavior by other means.

When a form is submitted via `<input type="image">`, the request has two more query fields (or form data fields), `x` and `y`, representing the clicked coordinate.
But if the input has a `name` attribute, both coordinates are prefixed by the value of the `name` attribute and a `.`.
We can define a function to submit a form with specified coordinates based on a given `<input type="image">` and call it.
The function basically needs to insert two `<input type="hidden">` elements with the correct `name` and `value` properties.
Upon form submission, these two fields are taken into account, automatically.

Here’s a demonstration of this function in action.

```js
const submitViaImage = (() => {
    const insertedElements = new WeakMap();
    
    return (button, x, y) => {
      if(button.form){
        if(insertedElements.has(button.form)){
          Array.from(insertedElements.get(button.form))
            .forEach((element) => element.remove());
        }
        else{
          insertedElements.set(button.form, new Set());
        }
        
        const prefix = (button.name
            ? `${button.name}.`
            : ""),
          hiddenX = Object.assign(document.createElement("input"), {
            name: `${prefix}x`,
            type: "hidden",
            value: x
          }),
          hiddenY = Object.assign(document.createElement("input"), {
            name: `${prefix}y`,
            type: "hidden",
            value: y
          });
        
        insertedElements.get(button.form)
          .add(hiddenX)
          .add(hiddenY);
        button.form.append(hiddenX, hiddenY);
        button.form.submit();
      }
    };
  })();


// Here, some event is bound to something that submits the form,
//   just demonstrating how to use the function above.

const target = document.querySelector("input[name='last']");

document.getElementById("somethingThatSubmitsTheForm")
  .addEventListener("click", () => submitViaImage(target, 40, 60));
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Some other data: <input name="someData" type="text"></label>
  <div>
    Submit:
    <input name="first" type="image" src="//picsum.photos/100?1">
    <input name="last" type="image" src="//picsum.photos/100?2">
  </div>
</form>

<input id="somethingThatSubmitsTheForm" type="button" value="Click here to submit the form via the second image at (40, 60).">
```

After clicking any of the buttons, you can inspect the iframe of the Stack Snippet to verify that its internal `documentURI` is indeed set to the expected URL with the `someData`, `first.x` or `last.x`, `first.y` or `last.y` fields.

Unfortunately, the form really needs to be directly submitted via `.submit()`; it’s not really possible to delegate submission via `button.click()` because this will attempt to overwrite the x and y coordinates resulting in something like `?last.x=0&last.y=0&last.x=40&last.y=60`.
However, `button.click()` is *preferred* when you expect form submission to be handled by an event listener with `preventDefault` called.
The x and y coordinates are not set in this case, but it correctly sets the `submitter` of the `SubmitEvent` among other things.

The function [closes over](//stackoverflow.com/q/30700027/4642212) a [`WeakSet`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) called `insertedElements`.
This is used to keep track of the elements added to any `<form>` so they can be removed before adding new ones.
Otherwise, more and more hidden inputs get added to the `<form>`s which will all be part of the submitted form data, containing obsolete data.
The inserted elements will be gone once the page reloads after form submission, but it’s still theoretically possible to load the submission response somewhere else, which is why removing the elements is still important.

Comment: Something that might need to be considered is the new [`submitter`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) argument in the `FormData` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you can use a MouseEvent, and set its x and y coordinate. I have also added a function to detect the mouse movements, to show that it works.

```js
// detect the mouse movement
document.addEventListener('click', function (event){
console.log(event.clientX, event.clientY)
})
// 
function click(x, y, element){
var click = new MouseEvent("click", {
    "view": window,
    "bubbles": true,
    "cancelable": false,
    "clientX":x,
    "clientY":y
});
element.dispatchEvent(click);
}
click(10, 20, document)
```

Comment: Did you try this code on the example URL? It  While the click detection is fine, the form/input is not submitted. Thus the page does not reload/the URL does not change.

Comment: What code exactly did you enter into the console? i am having trouble recreating the issue. For context, i am using chrome, and set the target to `"document.getElementById('image')"`

Comment: It seems Firefox and Chrome differ in behavior (understandable).
And console behavior differs from userscript behavior (?).
Firefox userscript will click the element at 0,0 no matter the coordinates (even if those coordinates are out of the element's bounds, e.g., 1000,1000), but does submit. 
Chromium userscript will click the element at the specified coords but 0,0 is the top left of the page, rather than the element, but does submit. 
In both Firefox and Chromium, using the console to run this code shows the coords in the console log but does not submit (noted in my first comment).

Comment: Regardless, thank you kindly for your answer and comments.